# Jquery make class back to original when I click in any part of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got 2 problems in that code, first the span tag does not working well should be white when is clicked, just happen once, I would like when I click anywhere in the page the icons and colours back to first stage, I mean before they are clicked, to asterisk and black.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/7/)

```js
$(".btn_body").click(function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star').css( "color", "white" );
      $(this).find('span').css('color', 'white');
      if ($(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").hasClass("glyphicon-star")) {
          $(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star').css( "color", "black" );
           $(this).find('span').css('color', 'black');
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" id="myform">
    <div class="body-title">title</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-16">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn_body" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span id="users_label">users</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-16">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn_body" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span id="clients_label">clients</span>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I''ve not fully understood your first problem but for the second you can do something like

```
$( ".btn_body" ).focusout(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star').css( "color", "black" );
})
```

If you look at this [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/15/) you will see the result.

Always if this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/15/), if you uncomment the line 2 ( which I added)

```
$(this).css('color', 'white');
```

Does it solves your first problem?

Answer (score 2):

Consider following code removed both problem:

```
  $(".btn_body").click(function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star');
      if ($(this).find("i").hasClass("glyphicon-star")) {
          $(this).find("i").css( "color", "white" );
      } else{
        $(this).find("i").css( "color", "black" );
      }
  });

$(document).on("click",function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var isTargetClick = !$target.add($target.parents()).is(".btn");
    if(isTargetClick){
    $(this).find('i').attr("class",'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk').css( "color", "black" );
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rtu1tzep/19/)

Answer (score 1):

I didnt understand your first problem. for the second one the below code will do

```
$(document).on("click",function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var isTargetClick = !$target.add($target.parents()).is(".btn");
    if(isTargetClick){
    $(this).find('i').attr("class",'glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk').css( "color", "black" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem you have to use on('click','#id',function(){ ...} instead of click().

```js
$(document).on('click','.btn_body',function () {
      $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star').css( "color", "white" );
      $(this).find('span').css('color', 'white');
      if ($(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").hasClass("glyphicon-star")) {
          $(".btn_body").not(this).find("i").toggleClass('glyphicon-asterisk glyphicon-star').css( "color", "black" );
           $(this).find('span').css('color', 'black');
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" id="myform">
    <div class="body-title">title</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-16">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn_body" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <span id="users_label">users</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-16">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle btn_body" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span id="clients_label">clients</span>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question, but I'll give it a go anyway.

Keeping the code that you have for changing the icons, you could detect clicks on the children of the body element (in theory, everything) and remove any instances of your desired class;

```
 $('body').on('click', '*', function(){
   // remove any instance of the 'glyphicon-star' class
   $('.glyphicon-star').removeClass('glyphicon-star');
 })
```